# Как запустить одну программу из другой?

Tags: java

Т. е. мне нужно, чтобы мой код запускал другой код.

Comment: Вы хотите из кода запустить приложение, или просто хотите использовать другой код в своем коде? Если последнее, то код на каком/каких языках вы хотите использовать?

Answer (score 2):

В заглавии и описании вопроса две разных задачи.
Если нужно программно выполнить другую программу, то можно воспользоваться методом [exec()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)):

```
try {
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /c \"dir && exit\"");
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Первый способ:

```
try {
    ProcessBuilder builder=
        new ProcessBuilder("notepad.exe", "text");

    builder.start();
}catch (Exception exc){
    System.out.println(exc);
}
```

Здесь мы запускаем программу Notepad(блокнот) и передаем в него файл *text*.

Второй способ говорил [@Kosmos](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/192199/kosmos), но я расширю его:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

Process process = null;

try{
    process=runtime.exec("Notepad");
    process.waitFor();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}

System.out.println("Программа блокнот вернула: "+process.exitValue());
```